# mysql insert value if it doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, insertion

I'm trying to insert an ingredient to an ingredients table if it doesn't exist.
I'm using the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO ingredient(Name) 
(
 SELECT 'ingName' FROM dummytable WHERE 
(SELECT count(*) FROM ingredient WHERE Name = 'ingName')=0)
```

This does not seem to work (0 rows affected), even though the SELECT query seem to return the desired result (an entry which contains "ingName").

The "ingredient" table has 2 columns: Name, id (id is auto incremented)

Thanks,
Li

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your inner query `SELECT count(*) FROM ingredient WHERE Name = 'ingName'` is returning a value > 0 and hence the upper query `SELECT 'ingName' FROM dummytable WHERE` is not selecting any rows and so no insert is happening.

I tried the same with a test table having 2 column `name|value` and it did worked fine

```
    INSERT INTO test1(name) (
    SELECT 'name' FROM test2 WHERE  
   (
      SELECT count(*) FROM test2 WHERE name = 'bilboa'
     )
   =0
   )
```

Inserted 2 rows with value `name` cause that's what I am selecting in select query and my test table 2 rows.

Answer (score 7):

Its better to add unique index on the `name` column:

```
ALTER TABLE `ingredient` ADD UNIQUE(`Name`)
```

After doing that you can use `INSERT IGNORE`:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `ingredient` ... /* anything */
```

Comment: this is a better solution for the problem

Comment: Thanks :) I will probably switch to this solution, but I was really curious to find out why my code didn't work...